# How create dynamic view page and css file in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on small project Fast Food Ads in Mvc3 using c# .I want to create page where user can set the layout of page like header , footer and menu bar etc. manually so I think this page its **HTML** and **Css** file should be create dynamically. page name and css file will be unique for every user
 how can i do this?
I don't want to use any CMS...

Answer (score 0):

In principal you can use the Razor engine in MVC3 to process any of your files.  You can already do that for your HTML files.

If you want to use Razor to dynamically process (or even create, on the fly) your CSS, have a look at [RazorJs](http://djsolid.net/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files).  RazorJs allows Razor to pre-process Javascript files before they are included in a view.  I have not looked at it's source code, but I imagine it should be straightforward to adapt it to pre-process CSS as well.

Comment: but problem is that how could generate css file and css attributes like margin , padding etc. because user can place images text on this page